# bounded below operator/ Kato-Rellich

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have shown that for a densely defined, self adjoint Operator D between Hilbert Spaces H, it holds
$\inf \sigma(D)\geq c$ Is this enough to conclude, that $D$ is bounded below by c, i.e. $ < x, Dx> \geq c <x,x>$ for all $x \in Dom(D)$? 
Edit: if so, can you provide me a proof?

Comment: For a selfadjoint $D$ on a Hilbert space $H$, it is enough.

Comment: Even if D is only densely defined? Can you give me a proof, ive been trying but i dont make progress